# How can I disable a parallax effect when the edge of a background image is revealed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to include a parallax element on my webpage but when the user scrolls too far, the white area behind the image shows, this problem is made harder because the full width of the image must be displayed.
Below is the code I'm using, I used a bit of chatGPT but it proved useless.

```css
/* styles.css */

body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  color: #777;
  line-height: 1.8;
}


/* Create a Parallax Effect */

.parallax-effect {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 400px;
  /* default min-height for all parallax-effect elements */
}


/* First image (Logo. Full height) */

.bgimg-1 {
  background-image: url('');
  min-height: 100%;
  /* specific min-height for .bgimg-1 */
}


/* Second image (Portfolio) */

.bgimg-2 {
  background-image: url("https://scontent.fcbr1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/376857960_277898621762859_1965680509669029177_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_p180x540&_nc_cat=111&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=5f2048&_nc_ohc=BtFqA-Xy_fgAX95Ufm0&_nc_ht=scontent.fcbr1-1.fna&oh=00_AfABhA0fRktKTtzgsSzvqhJcV0KdCrqewjFP6gNTVthsNw&oe=653BAB01");
  background-size: 100% auto;
  Background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 400px;
}


/* Third image (Socials!) */

.bgimg-3 {
  background-image: url("");
}

.w3-wide {
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

.w3-hover-opacity {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones */

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1600px) {
  .parallax-effect {
    background-attachment: scroll;
  }
}

.parallax-effect {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>W3.CSS Template</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">
  <!-- Update the href value with the correct path -->
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar (sit on top) -->
  <div class="w3-top">
    <div class="w3-bar" id="myNavbar">
      <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-black w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#home" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">HOME</a>
      <a href="#about" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#events" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small"><i class="fa fa-th"></i> EVENTS</a>
      <a href="#socials" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> SOCIALS!</a>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-right w3-hover-red">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Navbar on small screens -->
    <div id="navDemo" class="w3-bar-block w3-white w3-hide w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium">
      <a href="#about" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="toggleFunction()">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#events" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="toggleFunction()">EVENTS</a>
      <a href="#socials" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="toggleFunction()">SOCIALS!</a>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">SEARCH</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- First Parallax Image with Logo Text -->
  <div class="parallax-effect bgimg-1">
    <div class="w3-display-middle" style="white-space:nowrap;">
      <img src="" alt="SwiftSoc Logo">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Container (About Section) -->
  <div class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64" id="about">
    <h3 class="w3-center">ABOUT ME</h3>
    <p class="w3-center"><em>I love photography</em></p>
    <p>We have created a fictional "personal" website/blog, and our fictional character is a hobby photographer. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
      veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
      in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
      consequat.
    </p>
    <div class="w3-row">
      <div class="w3-col m6 w3-center w3-padding-large">
        <p><b><i class="fa fa-user w3-margin-right"></i>My Name</b></p><br>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/avatar_hat.jpg" class="w3-round w3-image w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off" alt="Photo of Me" width="500" height="333">
      </div>

      <!-- Hide this text on small devices -->
      <div class="w3-col m6 w3-hide-small w3-padding-large">
        <p>Welcome to my website. I am lorem ipsum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="w3-large w3-center w3-padding-16">Im really good at:</p>
    <p class="w3-wide"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i>Photography</p>
    <div class="w3-light-grey">
      <div class="w3-container w3-padding-small w3-dark-grey w3-center" style="width:90%">90%</div>
    </div>
    <p class="w3-wide"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>Web Design</p>
    <div class="w3-light-grey">
      <div class="w3-container w3-padding-small w3-dark-grey w3-center" style="width:85%">85%</div>
    </div>
    <p class="w3-wide"><i class="fa fa-photo"></i>Photoshop</p>
    <div class="w3-light-grey">
      <div class="w3-container w3-padding-small w3-dark-grey w3-center" style="width:75%">75%</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-row w3-center w3-dark-grey w3-padding-16">
    <div class="w3-quarter w3-section">
      <span class="w3-xlarge">14+</span><br> Partners
    </div>
    <div class="w3-quarter w3-section">
      <span class="w3-xlarge">55+</span><br> Projects Done
    </div>
    <div class="w3-quarter w3-section">
      <span class="w3-xlarge">89+</span><br> Happy Clients
    </div>
    <div class="w3-quarter w3-section">
      <span class="w3-xlarge">150+</span><br> Meetings
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Second Parallax Image with Portfolio Text -->
  <div class="parallax-effect bgimg-2">
    <div class="w3-display-middle">
      <span class="w3-xxlarge w3-text-white w3-wide">EVENTS</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The image in question is the second parallax image, any help is appreciated as I'm brand new to this.

I tried using JS but could only find resources for once it reaches the edge of the full display, but that didn't help my problem.